# Voltage Drop across an LED

Tags: led

I'm having a little trouble understanding as to what the voltage drop across an LED actually does in terms of the electrons. I understand that the potential difference across an LED causes the electrons to move and then undergo recombination to emit light, but why does it only happen significantly at a certain potential difference. What happens at lower potentials?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the current limiting resistor for an LED affect current and voltage drops?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/how-does-the-current-limiting-resistor-for-an-led-affect-current-and-voltage-dro)

Comment: @Passerby This question clearly isn't a duplicate of that one - this one is asking about the physics of how LEDs operate, not about current limiting with resistors.

Comment: @nick the answer for that question has a much better explanation on how diodes work, including current vs voltage. That graph especially.

Comment: @Passerby He's not asking how the forward voltage varies with current, though. He's asking "why does it only happen significantly at a certain potential difference" and "what [it] actually does in terms of the electrons".

Comment: hmm. Okay, retracted. The quality of this answer is lacking still.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode#Physics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An LED is a diode. A diode is a semiconductor. At potentials lower than the forward biased voltage drop, very little current would be flowing. As the potential rises, more current is able to pass through (exponentially).

For more information, research semiconductor doping.