# How does forward voltage work?

Tags: led, resistors

I had a small circuit with a few LEDs and a 10k ohm resistor, powered by a 5V pin from an Arduino.

I noticed that every time I added another if I had just one LED, then the resistor would drop most of the voltage, while the LED would only drop 1.6V. As I added another LED, now having two in the circuit along with a resistor, the resistor started to drop less voltage.

- So my question is, if I kept on adding LEDs, why does the voltage dropped by the resistor decrease, is it because the forward voltage does not change?
- What would happen if I added 10 LEDs, that have a forward voltage of 1.6V, only using an input of 5V, from my arduino, and a resistor?
- Would the resistor create no voltage drop?
- Would the forward voltage be reduced due to only providing 5V?
- Or would only a few LEDS light up?
- Why does voltage drop reduce for resistors and not LEDs?

Comment: Do some research on the current-voltage (I-V) characteristics of diodes.

Comment: See [Different voltage drop in serial and parallel circuit with resistor](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246359/different-voltage-drop-in-serial-and-parallel-circuit-with-resistor).

Comment: The voltage across the resistor dropped because the current was smaller. Adding LED's causes the current to be smaller. If you add enough LED's, the current will drop to zero and the voltage across the resistor will be zero and the LED's will not emit light.

Answer (score 2):

The current through a diode vs the voltage is a very steep curve. A small change in voltage results in a huge change in current. When you add another diode, it takes approximately the forward voltage to turn on and then after that it takes very little change in voltage for a huge change in current. A resistor on the other hand is a gentle linear curve. A change in voltage results in a very similar change in current on a resistor.

Because of these different dynamics, you get the effect you see. Diodes consume their forward voltage and not much more, and resistors absorb all the changes in voltage. If you have so many LEDs that result in the requirement of 10V of forward voltage but you only give the series 5V, then they will either not light at all or will very very dimly glow.

The forward voltage is nothing more than a simplification of the diode curve which is actually exponential in nature. The forward voltage just gives us a good approximation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_modelling

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you had an Ultrabright AlGaAs Red LED very dim at 0.3mA !

At this current it has a threshold of 1.6V in uA currents 
You should ge able to compute IR Voltage drop in the resistor for typically 2.1V @ 20mAmon AlGaAs Red.

The 5mm LEDS rated for 65mW have a 1/65mW = approx 16 Ohm ESR, ( give or take a wide margin)

So you have an effective linear (almost) Resistance in all diodes above the "knee" of the curve

The 1W rated LEDS are typically 1/1W or 1 Ohm ESR.

Thus my rule of Thumb is read the specs and once you know the knee voltage if you choose a supply just slightly above include the ESR of the diode using its rated power ESR= 1/Pd at the rated current.

For simple calculations Use Ohms law on the series resistor and compute the current which will now be shared in matched LEDs.

Then try 3V drop from 5.0V for 20mA and see if you get 3V on a 3/0.02A = 150 1% Ohm series resistor. If it is only a 2.9V drop then the LED is 2.1 but if the driver output changes 1000mV @20 mA then you have a 50 Ohm ESR CMOS driver (effectively )

Although I advise you read the driver (power and current) specs, BUT if you wanted to try and see 20mA then include the ESR of the driver and ESR of LED ,it's knee voltage such as 1.8V **for Red then I ={5-1.8}/ {ESR total } ** including ESR of driver, LED and battery if used.

So for 10mA  = (5.0-1.8) /Rtot

Rtot = 320 Ohms thus R - 50 -15 = 265

so choose 270 Ohms and verify these "assumptions"

Check driver power ratings and Vf and choose a conservative current  for your needs.