# Ned help modifying a Harbor Freight LED flashlight into a light source for a microscope

Tags: led, resistors, current-limiting

I have a couple of Harbor Freight free-when-you-buy-something-else flashlights. 
 I want to modify one of them into a light source for a microscope.  I've taken (**10**) of the (**24**) **white LEDs** off of one of the circuit boards and resoldered the remaining (**14**) (most of them were really poorly soldered). The original current limiting resistor was 1.5 ohms,5% for 24 LEDs and they were powered by 3 AAA batteries.
I would like to power the remaining (14) LEDs by tapping into the USB cable used for the digital microscope I'm using.
The LED microscope has a circle of LEDs built in for looking at opaque objects, but now I've got it mounted on a traditional microscope base with an adjustable stage (this thing is cool).  I want the (**14**) **LEDs** to be mounted in the base of the microscope so it will illuminate translucent objects (traditional glass microscope slides).  My question is, **what resistor value should I use to power the standard (14) white LEDs with 5V from the USB cable?**
I've attached a photo of HF flashlight circuit boards, one with all the LEDs still attached and the other that I'm modifying, including sanding the tops.
I'm not real experienced with electronics. I know enough to get in trouble.
[image: LED circuit boards (I sanded the tops of the LEDs)]

Comment: Knowing a bit about the reliability of things you pay for at Harbor Freight, I can't imagine how bad something would be that they give away for free.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21243/how-does-the-current-limiting-resistor-for-an-led-affect-current-and-voltage-dro or any of the hundreds of LED questions here.

Comment: http://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/ledcalc.php

Comment: 3.2V@20mA =64mW nom x14 LEDs = 900mW approx  or 280mA with a 1W R @ 6.4 Ohm 1.8V/0.28A or you can replace with a single 3W LED for <$2 on a DIY heatsink about 2"x2" https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cree-inc/XPGDWT-01-0000-00ME3/XPGDWT-01-0000-00ME3CT-ND/5994346 assuming your USB port supports it

Comment: you probably want around 5000K and you will get a lot more lumens/W out with the Cree part (about double)

Comment: about 100 ohms min, if they are all wired in parallel; it's not critical.

Comment: OK!  Thank you all. I'm going to try glen_geek's 18 ohms suggestion because I found the "Short answer" prefix enticing.  If that doesn't work and the LEDs burn out, there's plenty more of those lights where that one came from.  Ill make sure there's a switch that allows light from above or below, but not both at the same time. I'd like to throw in a pot to adjust brightness. I've got a 10k which is probably too much.

Comment: Here's the microscope I'm making the light source for.  The modified HF light should fit nicely in the round hole in the base.
I've taken some translucent sheets from the front of an old laptop screen and I cut circles out to filter and diffuse the light.
 <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppvea15aml8c082/Microscope.png?>

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: 18 ohms.
Your USB may be one that complies with the spec that limits current to 100 mA. If your LED circuit wants more, it may be cut off entirely. While USB may provide 500 mA, you must request the extra current via *enumeration*, which involves USB message transactions (something you don't want to get involved with). So to be safe, a 18 ohm quarter-watt resistor should limit current to your 14 parallel LEDs to 100 mA.

Tony Stewart provides a similar approach, suggesting a 6.4 ohm (one watt) resistor, which would provide about 280 mA. Your USB port may not comply with USB specifications and provide any current in which case, you can get more light with his method. But your USB source may balk and shut down because the load is beyond the 100 mA initial limit.

However, you have not said how much current your microscope-to-USB interface is flowing. Your extra LED illuminator will add to this current.

Comment: Very rare for a usb source to limit to 100 without enumeration. Most don't even limit to 500 ma either.